# Solving the limit of $\lim_{x\to 1-n} (\exp(2 \pi i x)-1)\Gamma(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, limits, gamma-function

I am reading the book Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields. I found the following limit on page number 33. I have no idea how to obtain the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\to 1-n} (e^{(2 \pi i x)}-1)\Gamma(x)=\frac{(2\pi i)(-1)^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Do we need to use L'Hospital's rule for this? 
Is there any connection with the residue of Gamma function at negative values?

The residue at $z=k$ is given by
$\operatorname{Re}s_{z=k} \Gamma(z)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}.$

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Should that be $\lim_{x\to1-n}\cdots$?

Comment: Yes, it should be $1-n$.

Comment: I think you mean the residue at $z=-k,$ not $z=k.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start:

Note that if $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$ then $f(1-n)=1$ when $n$ is an integer, and you can write your limit is $$\lim_{x\to 1-n} \frac{f(x)-f(1-n)}{x-(1-n)} \cdot (x-(1-n)) \Gamma(x)=f'(1-n) \cdot \lim_{n\to 1-n}(x-(1-n))\Gamma(x)$$

But $f'(1-n)=2\pi i$, so you need to show:

$$\lim_{x\to 1-n} (x-(1-n))\Gamma(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

This follows from your residue result (corrected to be at $z=-k$,) if you can show that the pole at $z=1-n$ is of degree $1.$

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don`t understand the last part. How can we get the result with the residue part? Is there a theory on that?

Comment: The residue for a function $f(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^{\infty} a_n(x-x_0)^k$ at $x=x_0$ is $a_{-1}$. If $N=-1,$ so the pole at $x_0$ is not of degree $2$ or more, then the reside at $x_0$ is $\lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)f(x).$ @SomaWick

Comment: I understood. Thank you